# Complex Fourier Transform Example

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

We briefly touched on Complex Fourier Transforms in my Complex Analysis class, which is extremely interesting to me since the Real Fourier Transform has so many applications in solving PDE's.  I am wondering what is an example where you explicitly need to use the Complex Fourier Transform in an application?

Note that the complex Fourier Transform is given by: Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function with $f(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and suppose there exists $a,C>0$ constants such that

$$
|f(z)|\le Ce^{a|z|}
$$

Then for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, there exists $\hat{f}(x)$ in $L^2([-a,a])$ such that

$$
f(z)=\int_{-a}^a \hat{f}(t)e^{itz}dt
$$

Comment: The text above the last equation is incomprehensible. It is even difficult to guess what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: I tried to reword it. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, this seems more coherent now. I assume that $f(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ means that $f$ is square-integrable over the entire real line.

Comment: Yeah, your assumption is correct!

Comment: You can use that theorem to prove that the Fourier transform of a compactly supported function is not compactly supported. But this extended Fourier transform is important to PDE's, see Hörmander, "The analysis of linear partial differential operators", Vol. I. You can find a lot of information about the subject, especially in chapter 7.3.